# jQuery replace match word with each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do i replace the text with each method?

Is it right? it doesnt replace / find the text correctly

```
$(function(){

   var style_find = ['tab-1','tab-2','rounded-1','rounded-2','tabs-1','tabs-2','tabs-alt-1','tabs-alt-2','tab-alt-1','tab-alt-2'];
   var cur_style = $('#obj').attr('class');
   var new_style;

   $(style_find).each(function(i,cl){
      new_style = cur_style.replace(cl,'new-class'); 
      // it doesnt replace the whole word
   });

})
```

Comment: [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Comment: Might be Syntax error see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ for reference.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.replace()` behaves differently depending upon the type of it's first parameter. Consider this code:

```
var example = "str str str str"; 
example = example.replace("str", "bob"); 
console.log(example === "bob str str str"); // === true?
```

I gave `replace()` a string for it's first parameter. When you do so, it only replaces the first occurrence of the substring.

When you call `replace()` with a RegExp you get something that returns all matches replaced

```
var example = "str str str str"; 
example = example.replace(/str/g, "bob"); 
console.log(example === "bob bob bob bob"); // === true
```

What we need is a regexp that matches everything you want to replace.

```
var style_find = ['tab-1','tab-2','rounded-1','rounded-2','tabs-1','tabs-2','tabs-alt-1','tabs-alt-2','tab-alt-1','tab-alt-2'];
var regexp = (function() { 
  var inner = ""; 
  style_find.forEach(function(el) { 
    inner = inner + el + "|";   
  }); 
  return new RegExp(inner, "g"); 
}());
```

With `regexp` I can modify your code to:

```
$(function(){
   var style_find = ['tab-1','tab-2','rounded-1','rounded-2','tabs-1','tabs-2','tabs-alt-1','tabs-alt-2','tab-alt-1','tab-alt-2'];
   var cur_style = $('#obj').attr('class');
   var new_style = cur_style.replace(regexp, 'new-class'); 
});
```